# Php copy public properties

Tags: php

I'm looking for a way to copy all the public properties from one object to another.

Comment: You're doing it wrong then. It's possible doing this using Reflection, and __set() method though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried the [get_object_vars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php)-function?

```
foreach(get_object_vars($a) as $prop => $value)
{
   $b->$prop = $value;
}
```

A more modern approach would be to use [Reflection](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php):

```
$reflect = new ReflectionClass($a);

foreach($reflect->getProperties(ReflectionProperty::IS_PUBLIC) as $prop)
{
   $name = $prop->getName();
   $b->$name = $prop->getValue();
}
```